# Google App Engine Rollback Failing - unable to download the source code of the app, in order to run the rollback - No local WAR avalible

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, jenkins, transactions

I'm trying to fix an issue with google app engine

The Dev team run Jenkins to do our deploys into Google App Engine. For some reason, two jobs were running concurrently and both tried to deploy into the same project. (I think, still working on it) - This caused the error

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=APP-ID&version=CURRENT-VERSION&
     [java] 409 Conflict
     [java] Another transaction by user SERVICEACCOUNT is already in progress for app: s~APP-ID, version: CURRENT-VERSION. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".
```

It turns out that I need to rollback a deployment - Okay, cool.

Why in the Blue Hell do I need the source code to do a rollback!?!? Google? what the hell?

From what I can see in documentation the original WAR is required in order to do this rollback. This I do not have, so I need the source code which I can get from google with

```
appcfg --download
```

This step only gets to 70% and then fails.

```
79% [6080/7641] __static__/static/blah/blah/blah/bundle.js
79% [6081/7641] __static__/static/yada/yada/yada/_all.js
79% [6082/7641] __static__/static/images/mapicons/awesome.png
Jul 13, 2016 5:56:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/files/get?id=9999&app_id=APP-ID&version=master.394126950949921946&
401 Unauthorized
Invalid OAuth token
This is try #0
```

I now how blocked projects, that I can no longer deploy into - Advice??

Answer (score 0):

You can use appcfg tool, which within your appengine_sdk/bin directory,  to rollback deployment. You need to have sufficient permissions to perform rollback.

```
appcfg --application=APP_ID --module=MODULE --version=VERSION rollback .
```

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appcfg-arguments

You need to have ./WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml on your path.

Or you could put ./WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>APP_ID</application>
    <version>MODULE</version>
    <module>VERSION</module>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Then your command would look like:

```
appcfg rollback .
```

Comment: if I don't have access to the appengine-web.xml - am I going to have a bad day?

Comment: You can just create one with content above.